# embed putty terminal together with tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Is it possible to embed or connect putty terminal together with tkinter gui to make it like one window?
for reference, some parts of the code are;

gui:

self.InWidget = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self.group1)

Open putty terminal:

app = Application().start(r".\putty.exe -ssh -l "+user+" -pw "+pswd+" "+ip+" ")
putty = app.PuTTY

Send command:

text = self.InWidget.get(line_start, line_end)
app = Application().connect(path='putty.exe', title=""+ip+" - PuTTY")

putty = app.PuTTY

putty.type_keys(""+text+"", with_spaces=True)

putty.type_keys('{ENTER}')

Comment: I am also having the same requirement. you got any idea on regarding this?